# Can salesforce be used as the IdP for customer portal user access to other service providers?

Tags: customer-portal, single-sign-on

Salesforce can be used as an [IdP](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/identity_provider_enable.htm) or [SP](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_tips.htm) when using SSO for non-portal users. It can also definitely be used as an [SP for portal user SSO](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_tips.htm#saml_portal_best_practices).

However I cannot find any definitive answer as to whether you can use salesforce as an IdP for customer portal users who want to SSO with other systems.

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Hello Wes - did you ever find a definitive answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself, but [this page of documentation](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/identity_provider_portals_sites.htm) implies that yes, you can define external SP's (with Salesforce as the IdP) for both Force.com Sites and Customer Portals.

You'd want to do a quick test yourself to verify. SSO documentation is very sparse and after getting burned on undocumented gotchas that affected a big Portal SSO project I now wouldn't embark on any SOO project based on documentation alone, it's got to start with a working proof-of-concept.

Comment: Yes, in a general sense, this is absolutely possible. But I believe that details and documentation are sparse on this because there are so many different variables that will vary from application to application. [This article](https://digitalmass.com/how-we-think/authenticate-experience-cloud-users-salesforce-sso/#:~:text=Authenticating%20External%20Experience%20Cloud%20Users%201%20If%20they,implements%20the%20server%20side%20of%20OpenID%20Connect%E2%80%99s%20protocol.) does a good job articulating why it's hard to find details on this but also what solutions generally exist.